# Long querystring in LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I am generating a linkbutton dynamically and setting its postbackurl by iterating over a collection the linkbutton shows the correct url when i hover mouse over it but when i click the linkbutton only three of intended five querystring parameters are passed.
I,m using Firefox
here's my code

```
    foreach(var item in collection)
{
linkbutton b = new linkbutton();

linkbutton.postbackurl="somepage.aspx?" + "param1="+ item.val1 + "&param2=" + item.val2
                       + "&param3=" + item.val3+ "&param4=" + item.val4+ "&param5="
                       +item.val5;  
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

however when i click the linkbutton browser opens

```
somepage.aspx?param1=val1&param2=val2&param5=val5
```

all values are present in the collection item
plus the browser ignores param3,4 in the link itself
:<
 once again HELP!!!

Comment: I dont think its an issue but the plus + symbol in the string concatenation next to val3 and val4 are right next to each other. Try adding a space. The C# compiler shouldnt have a problem with the way you have it though but step through it to ensure the postbackurl is set to what you expect

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in place to verify that the postback URL get's correctly set?

Comment: wats a breakpoint(like i wanna break this computer right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario you just need an `asp:HyperLink` not need of a `asp:LinkButton`. There are some errors in your code. A more optimised / readable version will be this

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
    var btn = new HyperLink();

    btn.NavigateUrl=String.Format("somepage.aspx?param1={0}&param2={1}&param3={2}&param4={3}&param5={4}",
                item.val1,
                item.val2,
                item.val3,
                item.val4,
                item.val5);  
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You made my day dear friend Thanx a million but still wondering why my code did not produce right result.Any comments why it was wrong????And Yes THANK YOU